Remove the windows titlebar from the window by having it HWND
I have a window with known HWND, and i want to remove default windows titlebar and save hide/minimize/maximize animations from Windows 11
I tried to customize     SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, style); but it removes win11 animations

Is the window in your process?

No, this is JavaFX window, and i run c++ with JNI

You can't expect to modify windows in other processes. Why would you even try that?

@DavidHeffernan window style is managed by the Windows shell and not drawn by the app, so you can change it. IIRC there are lots of theming apps like that in the past

@phuclv yeah, apart from all the apps that draw their own chrome. These questions are fun but they aren't real.

I didn't find a solution to implement titlebar from 0, saving all animations from Windows 11, but I was able to make the regular titlebar dark, which also looks good.
    HWND hwnd = YOUR_WINDOW_HWND;

    BOOL USE_DARK_MODE = true;
    BOOL SET_IMMERSIVE_DARK_MODE_SUCCESS = SUCCEEDED(DwmSetWindowAttribute(
        hwnd, DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE::DWMWA_USE_IMMERSIVE_DARK_MODE,
        &USE_DARK_MODE, sizeof(USE_DARK_MODE)));
    return 0;


Oh, okay) I forgot to do it

You could try to call GetWindowLongPtr first to retrieve information about the specified window. And then you could clear the WS_CAPTION in the window style. Aboud how to remove the styles you don't want, you could refer to the thread: Removing window border?
style=GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_STYLE) & ~WS_CAPTION


I know about WS_CAPTION, but it removes Win11 animations, and small peace of titlebar remains. Window is created by JavaFX
